# AJAX: Store PHP data in a Javascript variable

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

As stated in the title, I have an ajax call. On the success function I want to store the returned data into a variable for use in my javascript. randNum.php simply returns a random number every 2 seconds, and I would like to use that number for other functions in my scripts. How can I use the data sent back from the php file in my javascript?
I know there are more logical ways to go about this, but want to know how to accomplish the task this way.

```
    var result;
    var interval = 2000;
    function myCall() {
        var request = $.ajax({
            url: "randNum.php",
            type: "GET",            
            dataType: "html",
            success:function (msg) {
                result = msg;  //Not working as I intend
                setTimeout(myCall, interval);
            }
        });
    }

function(){
    do something with result;
}
```

Comment: if the only purpose of the randNum.php is to generate a random number every 2 seconds - why don't you simply have a js function that does that in the page and save the server load? getting a number every 2 seconds multiplied by the number of users viewing your page will lead to heavy traffic when you can call a random number in javascript - or even have a php function in the page that generates the number.

Comment: @gavgrif I know I can do that, I'm asking how to generally store data from a php file into a useable javascript variable. This is just for learning purposes, nothing to be used in real world applications.

Comment: the answer to that is to call the function from the success event of the Ajax call (... displayNumber(result)... ) where displayResult is a function that takes the result value and does stuff with it. But its still the wrong approach to take with this exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Declare a Global variable outside of the function and assign response variable to it after the ajax response.

```
var results;
function TestJSONP(){
    $.ajax({
        url: "randNum.php",
        jsonp: "callback",
        dataType: "jsonp",

        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response);
            results = response;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Since you just obviously copy-pasted this answer (where on earth is the `q` come from?); might be better to just link to the answer you are referring to.

Comment: Eliminate the block and try it, have something similar am working on OpenMRS at the moment, only mines posts back data upon query submit, just giving you something to work with.

Answer (score 0):

You might not need to specify `dataType`, but use `jqXHR.responseText` to get the raw response. Something like

```
function myCall() {
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: "randNum.php",
        type: "GET",            
        success:function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            result = jqXHR.responseText;  
            setTimeout(myCall, interval);
        }
    });
}
```

When you set `dataType`, and the response is not that type, then the ajax did not succeed and `error` call back will be invoked.